# Moving several elements within array to a certain index in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of elements.

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

user can pick any number of elements and ask to move them after any 1 particular element.

example: ask for 4,5,7 to be moved after 1 for example, thus resulting in

0,1,4,5,7,2,3,6,8,9

or ask for 0,5 to be moved after 9

1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0,5

any pseudo code is greatly appreciated.

```
                move_after= function(after, move_array) {
                    //remove elements from the array
                    move_array.forEach(function(element) {
                        var index = operations.indexOf(element);
                        operations.splice(index, 1);
                    });


                    var after_index = operations.indexOf(after) + 1;

                    //insert each move_array element to array
                    move_array.forEach(function(element) {
                         operations.splice(after_index++, 0, element);
                    });
                }

                move_after(2, [0,1]);
```

doesn't exactly give me what i want

Answer (score 1):

Here a **prototype** is used, which **inserts** an array into an array after a specific digit:

```
Array.prototype.insertIntoArr = function(insert, digit) {
    var i = this.indexOf(digit) + 1;
    return this.slice(0, i).concat(insert).concat(this.slice(i));
}
```

The `function moveAfter( ... )` first *cleans* the array from the values of `toMove`. Second `toMove` is inserted after the specific digit:

```
function moveAfter(arr, toMove, after) {
    toMove.forEach(function (value) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1);
    });
    var res = arr.insertIntoArr(toMove, after);
    return res;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/trt6798y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/k2h6BWTUCFj5BS4oFF8C

```
(function(){
  var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var userArr = [4,5,7];
  var temp = [];
  var pos = 1;

  for(var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--){
    if(userArr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1){
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(pos) + 1, 0, temp[i]);
  }

  console.log(arr);
  //outputs [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your idea

```
function move_after(orig_array, after, move_array) {
                //remove elements from the array
                move_array.forEach(function(element) {
                    var index = operations.indexOf(element);
                    orig_array.splice(index, 1);
                });

                var after_index = orig_array.indexOf(after) + 1;

                //insert each move_array element to array
                move_array.forEach(function(element) {
                     orig_array.splice(after_index++, 0, element);
                });
          return orig_array;
}
```

Then you use

```
var result = move_after([0, 1, 2] , 2, [0,1]);
```

Hope it works,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
move_after = function (after, move_array) {
  var i, s;

  s = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    // only append "i" it if is NOT in move_array
    if (move_array.indexOf(i) === -1) s.push(i);
    if (i == after) s.push(move_array);
  }

  return s;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var b = move_after(1, [4, 5, 7]);
var c = move_after(9, [0, 5]);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);

function move_after(moveAfter, toMove) {
    var arr = a.reduce(function (c, e, i) {
        if (toMove.indexOf(e) === -1) {
            c.push(e);
        }
        return c;
    }, []);
    var toMoveAfterIndex = arr.indexOf(moveAfter) + 1;
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(
        arr, [toMoveAfterIndex, 0].concat(toMove)
    );
    return arr;
}
```